# Taking XML from a XMLHTTPRequest and utilizing the data in Jquery/html/javascript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, usps

Hello friendly people,

Recently a tool we use at our department has broken and it used to give us tracking information based on HTML structure. This is inefficient because it relys on the website staying the same.

I have now gotten my hands on the API usps gives for tracking data. The problem is it's my first time using an API.

Below is my XMLhttp request - With this I get a response which is also in xml.

```
http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=TrackV2&XML=(seebelow)
<TrackRequestUSERID="xxxxxxxx">
<ID="EJ123456780US"></TrackID>
<TrackID ID="EJ123456781US"></TrackID>
<TrackID ID="12345"></TrackID>
</TrackRequest>
```

above is the signature they provide and the an example request. and below this line is what the response looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TrackResponse><TrackInfo ID="EJ958083578US"><TrackSummary>
Your item was delivered at 8:10 am on June 1 in Wilmington DE 19801.
</TrackSummary><TrackDetail>
May 30 11:07 am NOTICE LEFT WILMINGTON DE 19801.
</TrackDetail><TrackDetail>
May 30 10:08 am ARRIVAL AT UNIT WILMINGTON DE 19850.
</TrackDetail><TrackDetail>
May 29 9:55 am ACCEPT OR PICKUP EDGEWATER NJ 07020.
</TrackDetail></TrackInfo></TrackResponse>
```

In terms of utilizing this XML / data i have no idea where to go on from here, I just spent like 2 hours getting the request to work which I am excstatic about but what can I do to send in multiple tracking numbers and have them populate a table??

Any help appreciated!

Comment: `TrackRequestUSERID=”xxxxxxxx”` should very likely be `TrackRequestUSERID="xxxxxxxx"`.

Comment: Well yes, but I already have that part working, This was just an example pasted from the USPS documentation - also this was just a difference in font im pretty sure